# Abelian isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if G and G' are isomorphic groups and G is abelian, then G' is abelian, too.

I'll happy if you help me with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with what you need to prove: Given $a,b\in G'$, we need to show that $ab=ba$. Now, use the fact that the groups are isomorphic, so there exists an isomorphism $\psi:G\to G'$ with inverse function, also an isomorphism, $\varphi:G'\to G$. Now, compute $ab$ by using these functions to 'transfer' the computation from $G'$, which you don't (yet) know is abelian, to $G$, which you do know is abelian. Can you proceed?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't complete the transformation.. Can you please solve? :/

Comment: any more information and I will be solving the problem entirely. Keep trying.

Comment: Since G is abelian, we can say φ(ab)=φ(a)φ(b)=φ(b)φ(a)=φ(ba). This shows that ab=ba. But i know this is wrong..

Comment: what is wrong???

Comment: Really? Is it true? :D

Comment: well, if you are not clear why your argument is correct, then, no, you did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$ be an isomorphism.  Since $ab = ba$ for any $a, b \in G$, consider $\phi(ab)$ and $\phi(ba)$.

Keep in mind the fact that, for any group homomorphism, $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$.